# pandas moving aggregate string

Tags: string, pandas, concatenation

```
from pandas import *

import StringIO

df = read_csv(StringIO.StringIO('''id   months  state
1   1   C
1   2   3
1   3   6
1   4   9
2   1   C
2   2   C
2   3   3
2   4   6
2   5   9
2   6   9
2   7   9
2   8   C
'''), delimiter= '\t')
```

I want to create a column show the cumulative state of column state, by id.

```
id  months  state   result
1   1   C   C
1   2   3   C3
1   3   6   C36
1   4   9   C369
2   1   C   C
2   2   C   CC
2   3   3   CC3
2   4   6   CC36
2   5   9   CC69
2   6   9   CC699
2   7   9   CC6999
2   8   C   CC6999C
```

Basically the cum concatenation of string columns. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

So long as the `dtype` is `str` then you can do the following:

```
In [17]:
df['result']=df.groupby('id')['state'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
df

Out[17]:
    id  months state    result
0    1       1     C         C
1    1       2     3        C3
2    1       3     6       C36
3    1       4     9      C369
4    2       1     C         C
5    2       2     C        CC
6    2       3     3       CC3
7    2       4     6      CC36
8    2       5     9     CC369
9    2       6     9    CC3699
10   2       7     9   CC36999
11   2       8     C  CC36999C
```

Essentially we [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on 'id' column and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a lambda with a [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to return the [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). This will perform a cumulative concatenation of the string values and return a `Series` with it's index aligned to the original df so you can add it as a column